# setting state not setting in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
  this.setState({loading: true}, () => {
            if (googleUser && googleUser.profileObj) {
                app.auth().signOut();
                // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
                var unsubscribe = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
                    unsubscribe();
                    // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
                    if (!this.isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
                        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
                        var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                            googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
                        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
                        app.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
                            // Handle Errors here.
                            var errorCode = error.code;
                            var errorMessage = error.message;
                            // The email of the user's account used.
                            var email = error.email;
                            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                            var credential = error.credential;
                            this.setState({error: errorMessage, loading: false})
                        }).then(() => {
                            app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                                if (user) {
                                    user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
                                        // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
                                        // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
                                        const csrfToken = Utils.getCookie('csrfToken');
                                        this.postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/auth/session-login', idToken, csrfToken, 'google', googleUser.profileObj.googleId);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    this.setState({error: "There was an error", loading: false});
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    } else {
                        this.setState({error: "You are already signed in.", loading: false});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The code is not working, it's not setting loading to true and not re-rendering before invoking the callback function in setState.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: React combines fast changes to the state, it may simply not render between the `loading` being set to `true` and then back to `false`. How do you know it's not changing the state?

Comment: because I don't see the spinner that shows up if loading is false

Comment: Have you tried commenting out your callback? Like I said, it's possible react is combining the state updates and loading is being set twice before it ever renders the spinner.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that this code is being run? Where is it in your component, relative to everything else (callback, function, etc.)? As was suggested by @DBS, when you remove the callback, does the state change?